# How do i add json list containing json strings to a .json file and how do i read from it?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a maps that i would like to add to the .json file as json strings using a for loop. And I want to be able to read from the same .json file and be able to deserialize the returned list and loop through it. All I have tried has failed so far. Here is the code I am using:

```
Future writeHistory(Map<String, dynamic>? map) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    //read the file
    final info = await readHistory();
    //deserialize to a list
    final infoObj = convert.jsonDecode(info);
    //serialize the passed in map
    final jsonStr = convert.jsonEncode(map);
    //check if the file as any info and if not append the serialized map to infoObj, serialize infoObj and write to file
    if (info.isEmpty) {
      return file.writeAsString(convert.jsonEncode([jsonStr]),
          mode: FileMode.write);
    }
    infoObj.add(jsonStr);
    return file.writeAsString(convert.jsonEncode(infoObj), mode: FileMode.write);
  }


  Future readHistory() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      final contents = await file.readAsString();
      return convert.jsonDecode(contents);
    } catch (e) {
      return [''];
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the specific issue/error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, when you are adding a new JSON string to the existing list in infoObj, you need to make sure that infoObj is initialized properly if the file is empty. Also, when writing to the file, you should convert the list to a JSON string directly instead of wrapping it in another array.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
Future<void> writeHistory(Map<String, dynamic>? map) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    // read the file
    final info = await readHistory();
    // deserialize to a list
    final infoObj = info.isEmpty ? [] : convert.jsonDecode(info);
    // serialize the passed-in map
    final jsonStr = convert.jsonEncode(map);
    // check if the file has any info and if not, append the serialized map to infoObj,
    // serialize infoObj, and write to file
    if (info.isEmpty) {
      return file.writeAsString(jsonStr, mode: FileMode.write);
    }
    infoObj.add(jsonStr);
    return file.writeAsString(convert.jsonEncode(infoObj), mode: FileMode.write);
  }

Future<String> readHistory() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      if (await file.exists()) {
        final contents = await file.readAsString();
        return contents;
      }
      return '';
    } catch (e) {
      return '';
    }
  }

Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = 'your_file_path_here.json'; // Replace with your file path
    return File(path);
  }
```

Here are the changes made:

1.Initialized infoObj as an empty list if info is empty.
2.Removed the unnecessary array wrapping when writing to the file.

Make sure to replace 'your_file_path_here.json' with the actual file path you are using.

With these changes, the writeHistory function should now correctly handle both empty and non-empty cases when appending to the file.